# CakePHP is truncating a text field, probably encoding related

Tags: php, cakephp, character-encoding

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm parsing incoming email, and using it to create posts in the system.  This works almost completely, but there's a few bugs to work out.  The one that's currently giving fits is coming up when an email contains certain characters (for example, ® – “ ”), the email body is being truncated at the special character when inserting in to the database.  It's happening during the $Model->save() call.

The email is not UTF-8 encoded (and since any user can send email, we can't control the incoming mail encoding), but the database is UTF-8.  It seems to work correctly when the email comes in as UTF-8.

Any suggestions?  Is there a way to convert the encoding before attempting to save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the database chokes at the point where you are trying to insert ISO-8859-1 (or some other encoding) special characters into a UTF-8 encoded mySQL table.

The only proper way to deal with this would be to determine the incoming E-Mail's encoding, and do an **[`iconv()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)** on it.

I've never dealt with incoming E-Mail in this detail but to determine UTF-8 encoding, I think this goes into the right direction: [**iconv_mime_decode**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-decode.php)

You could also try to sniff the encoding using [**mb_detect_encoding**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) but this is deemed unreliable as far as I know.

Comment: iconv() did the trick, along with imap_fetchstructure() to determine the encoding.